# Jasmine Unit Testing on extjs

Tags: jasmine, extjs4.2

I would like to ask for some advice on how do you write jasmine unit test for extjs store? Stores that connects to the database to retrieve data. Do people write such unit test?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is practical to unit test a store. The setup depends on the environment and how the tests are run, but I'd expect it to be the same as any of your other unit tests. Set up the class paths, and load Ext and the store class with the Microloader or with Ext.Loader in a before block like [beforeAll](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/global.html#beforeAll). A set of [it](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-It's_Just_Functions) blocks might create the store themselves to test initialization. Other describe blocks may create the store in a before block and test post-initialization functionality. Use the [done](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) method to handle asynchronous operations and, if desired, [mock the ajax](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/mocking_ajax) requests so that a Web server and database are not required to perform the tests.